# what exactly are driver functions?

Tags: c++

I'm working through "Accelerated C++".  I have a question about problem 5-3.  It asks:

```
5-3. By using a typedef, we can write one version of the program that implements either a
vector-based solution or a list-based one. Write and test this version of the program.'
```

The next question asks:

```
5-4. Look again at the driver functions you wrote in the previous exercise. Note that 
it is possible to write a driver that differs only in the declaration of the type for the data structure
that holds the input file. If your vector and list test drivers differ in any other way, rewrite them
so that they differ only in this declaration.
```

What exactly are driver functions?  I've solved 5-3 by creating if statements as well as overloaded functions to deal with different datatypes like so:

```
cout << "Please enter 1 if you would like to use vectors, or 2 if you would like to use lists: "<< endl;
int choose;
cin >> choose;
//CHOOSING TO USE VECTORS
if (choose == 1){....vector<Student_info> allStudents;
                 vector<Student_info> fail;.......} 

//CHOOSING TO USE LISTS
else if (choose==2) {....list<Student_info> allStudents;
                    list<Student_info> fail;....}

//INVALID CHOICE
else {...invalid number, try again...}
```

I did not create any extra functions besides the overloaded ones to deal with different data types.  Are those driver functions?  If not, I must be doing the problem wrong.  Could someone shed some light? :>

Comment: You might want to read this 2005 thread. http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/167496-accelerated-c-clarification-wording-exercises

Comment: Driver functions are probably functions that are written to demonstrate operation of some library-style code that solves the problem. For example, if you write some class `A`, driver functions would be functions that are in your code just to show that class `A` behaves as expected. So, the first driver function would be `main` itself, and then any other function called from `main` that are clients of the `A` class.

Comment: For a book that comes so highly recommended, the writing is often comically atrocious. There are multiple threads all over the internet trying to parse what the heck they are actually asking with certain questions. I've been tempted to literally re-write the questions so that they can be understood without an internet search. (Yes it would be ironic) Does this show how sorry the state of C++ pedagogy is, if this is on the top list despite its undeniable flaws.

Comment: I agree that some of the questions are poorly written and confusing.  But overall, I am a fan of the book thus far.  I feel I've learned quite a bit for the time i've spent studying c++ and have written a good number of programs with the concepts taught throughout. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your two `if` blocks, how similar is the code that operates on `allStudents` and `fail` regardless of whether they are `list` or `vector`?  If you've done the assignment correctly, there is probably little or no difference.  Now if you take that code out and remove references to `list` and `vector` and instead operate on `mytype` where you build either with `typedef vector<Student_info> mytype` or `typedef list<Student_info> mytype` you will have what they were calling a "driver function".  It's not a formal name you're going to find internet references to.  They were just describing the code that *drives* the `list` and `vector` operations to get the answer.

Comment: The two blocks of code are identical besides the typedef! If I did something like this:

    `if (choose == 1){
            typedef vector<Student_info> mytype;
    }
    else if (choose == 2){
        typedef list<Student_info> mytype;
    }
    else {
        cout << "invalid number "<< endl;
        main();
        return 0;
    }
    ....mytype<Student_info>.....
`

would the if statements be considered the driver functions?

Comment: @DavidJhoo I think the specific goal of the question was to get you to split that into a *function* (which might require separate compilation with `typedef` to get different types) because I bet the next thing they're going to do is introduce *templates* and show you how you can now have a "multi type driver function" (to use the awkward language of the question)

Comment: Ok. That makes sense.  I've been trying to think of ways to define the `typedef` of `mytype` through a function and referencing.  But I'm not exactly sure how to do this. How would I return a typedef, or reference an object that I can assign a typedef to? Or is that an incorrect approach?

Comment: After more self-thinking, that seems like the wrong approach. I would have to be able to return an arbitrary type which I don't think is possible...

Comment: @DavidJhoo Right, the `typedef` solution would require compiling first one way and then the other (e.g. by changing the source or with `#ifdef`).  A template would let you write the function once and then *instantiate* it multiple times for different types by calling `function<type>(args)`.  Don't get too hung up on this intermediate step.  If their attempt to lead you to the idea of templates gradually is confusing, ignore it and go direct!

Comment: Alright, I've been working on this for several hours now.  I'll come back to this later after a few chapters.  I'm hoping the thought I put in will make the EUREKA effect more potent in the later chapters. Hah. :>

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, driver code is a more obscure way to say **test code**.

In other words the author is suggesting you take a look at the test (aka driver) code you used to verify the code you wrote in 5-3.